# Unknown host on Burp Suite when trying to access *.localhost

Tags: burp-suite, sub-domain

I am trying to analyze HTTP traffic of our application.
Application has two accessible portals, one accessible by `admin.localhost:3002` and the other accessible by `localhost:3002`

I have Burp Suite proxy on `127.0.0.1:8080`, certs configured in firefox and localhost hijacking enabled in config.

Access to `localhost:3002` works fine but when it tries to access `admin.localhost:3002` (or any other subdomain) it shows `Unknown Host: admin.localhost`

I can't create a resolver as I do not have access to sudo.
How do I configure Burp Suite to resolve `*.localhost`?

Comment: Do you need to? Can't you simply send a custom hostname in the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom hostname:IP mappings in Burp Suite in `Settings > Network > Connections > Hostname Resolution Overrides`, although I'm not sure that you can use wildcards there.

Alternatively, you could add an entry to your hosts file that points `admin.localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, although again it doesn't support wildcards and would probably need sudo privileges.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but something to point out is that when doing this it stops treating localhost as secure and things like cookies need to be changed to not SecureOnly and other things, like using geolocation, stop working